# Best way to setup SSH to permanent IP for a dynamic IP on home internet?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn, ip-address

I have a special computer at home which I'd like to be able to just SSH to without any worries about a change in my IP address. Of course I'm in an area with only Comcast, and I don't want to deal with the high cost and technical interaction of getting a fixed IP from them.

I'd prefer some way to have my host machine hooked up to either a VPN, or tunneled through a cheap VPS that already has fixed IP. My end objective is just to be able to reliably reach my home-host which is running all my Jupyter projects.

Is there any easy way to do this? I already pay for NordVPN, and I have it active, but just connecting to VPN clearly isn't enough. I think there must be additional routing rules, and I'm not sure what those are or where to set them up.

OR, instead, I could figure out how to do some sort of SSH bridge from my dedicated ubuntu VPS on linode, but if the IP address of my dynamic home IP changed, I'd need the bridge to initialize from the home device and routinely check the connection. It sounds like a more daunting task.

Anyway - I have no background in networking other than using SSH and UFW, so I'm totally in over my head here. I really just want some good starting points for doing something like this and I'm not quite sure for the right terminology to be searching for.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

[Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) is probably your best option. Register a domain, and set up a host name within the domain to update its DNS record whenever your IP address changes. Then you can always connect to your server using that host hame.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, that worked for me. Figured out how to do it directly with my router too so that I could forward to multiple machines. Great stuff!